# React components constantly re-rendering in AngularJS app with ngReact

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

Wondering if anybody else has run into this issue when using React and AngularJS/ngReact. I noticed that, at the boundary between AngularJS and React, the very first component constantly re-renders. It's not an infinite loop but it's definitely many unnecessary re-renders, no props have changed. The only thing I can think of is maybe something is mutating the angular scope / root scope and React is interpreting that as a props change and re-renders when the new angular scope / root scope is passed down.

Comment: Hard to tell without an example of the implementation but make sense your guessing.